# Composing GraphQL queries

Tags: graphql

Suppose a GraphQL schema supports the following queries:

```
{
    person(id: String) {
        locationId
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    location(id: String) {
        country
    }
}
```

Is it possible to find a `person` by `id`, then use the resulting `locationid` to find their `location` by `id` (returning the `country` corresponding to that `location`) all the in a single query?

Or would I have to make two separate queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the only information on a `location` that you can get from a `person` then yes, you will need to perform two queries in separate requests.

It would be more normal for a GraphQL schema to present the whole `location` node as visible from the `person` (i.e. the id's would be dereferenced, though perhaps still available), and if a `person` could have more than one `location` then you would follow the `locations` edge to get to each `location` node.

Answer (score 5):

The query would look like this;

```
{
    person(id: string){
        location{
            country
        }
    }
}
```

In your person type, you can apply a resolver to the `location` field which gets the location based on the locationId of the person which the query is performed against.